# CSS floats and block elements

Tags: html, css, layout, cross-browser

I have an annoying CSS layout problem.  I'm trying to float images on a particular page:

```
img {
  float: left;
}
```

I think make sure my headings don't start indented with:

```
h3 {
  clear: left;
}
```

It all works fine except for some of the images that have lists (or any block element) floating past them (or not as the case is).  The reason for this is actually clear in the CSS spec: block elements don't flow.  Line/inline elements do.

This is a real problem for lists however.  Is there any way around it in a fairly generic and compatible way?

Comment: I think I can visualize the problem you are talking about, but a screenshot would be very helpful nevertheless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I always do to make sure the float is always cleared:

1. Add the following to the CSS:

   ```
   .clearfix:after {
       content: ".";
       display: block;
       clear: both;
       visibility: hidden;
       line-height: 0;
       height: 0;
   }

   .clearfix {
       display: inline-block;
   }

   html[xmlns] .clearfix {
       display: block;
   }

   `*` html .clearfix {
       height: 1%;
   }
   ```

   You can also find this code [here](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html).
2. Mark every parent of the element that's floated with class `clearfix`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what this does and why.  Also how does it handle in IE6/7?

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like the problem is with clearing floats.  But as a comment said, a screenshot would be nice.  I personally clear my floats by setting the overflow property: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html